# Can the energy/power required to mix two fluids together be calculated?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, work, diffusion

Given two fluids; say for example oxygen and nitrogen gases.

By simply introducing, again for example 1 liter of each gas into a closed container, the process of diffusion alone will eventually cause the gases to reach a homogeneous mixture throughout the container. And I believe the time it takes to accomplish heterogeneity (to some specified percentage) can be estimated using a diffusion model, knowing the gas temperatures,fluid, and container properties (as a partial differential equation)

But what if mechanical work is involved? Say for example a paddle wheel is introduced into the container that can be rotated. Is there a way to calculate how long it would take to reach homogeneity in this case?

I suspect I might need to know the speed of the wheel and its surface area/geometry. But can it more easily simplified in terms of work input? So then a function that provides mix percentage as a function of time, work input, temperature and initial conditions.

Or is this type of problem just so complex that it requires empirical reduction?

Comment: Definitely requires a full numerical model of the shape of the container, shape and speed of the paddle, etc. Just knowing the work is not going to help.

Answer (score 0):

To give you the idea of the complexity of this problem, consider that the dynamics of a single fluid is governed by the Navier-Stokes equation, which is already impractical to solve.

$$\frac {\partial}{\partial t} (\rho  u) + \nabla \cdot (\rho u \otimes u + p I)  =  \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol \tau + \rho g$$

Then this equation is coupled to probably three diffusion equations, one for the temperature, and one for the diffusion of each gas.

$$\frac{\partial\phi(\mathbf{r},t)}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \big[ D(\phi,\mathbf{r}) \ \nabla\phi(\mathbf{r},t) \big]$$

And don't forget you need to solve these equations on varying boundary conditions, as a result of the paddle wheel. This is the kind of problem that gets researched in computational fluid dynamics labs, or maybe companies that need to understand in detail the dynamics of certain chemical reactions.